# VSCode formatting ternary incorrectly within React's JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, eslint

I am running VSCode to develop my React app. I have a simple ternary:

```
{isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
) : (
    <Content />
)}
```

...however, when I save it gets formatted to this:

```
{isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
) : (
        <Content />
)}
```

...and my linter (correctly) gives me the following error:

> Expected indentation of 5 tabs but found 6 eslint/indent

Whenever I CTRL+S the indentation corrects itself for a split second, then goes back to the incorrect state with the red lines indicating a problem.

The issues is that my VSCode settings have this:

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

...and I also have this:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll": true
},
```

My linter and the VSCode formatting are conflicting. However, even when I disable all the default formatting options from my settings.json file, this issue persists. If I turn off `formatOnSave`, the issue re-appears when I manually format the code.

I don't see why they cannot co-exist. Why is my VSCode formatter messing up my JSX even when I don't specify anything in my settings.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find to this was to turn off the auto-formatting and rely entirely on ESLint to format my code, then to manually format (using `ALT+SHIFT+F`) when I want.

This is not ideal but there does not appear to be an alternative. I am happy to be corrected.