# disable multiline ternary in prettier

Tags: javascript, prettier, prettier-vscode, prettier-standard

Is there way to config prettier to prevent not multi line the ternary operation?

wanted this:

```
const route = routeModule.config ? routeModule.config(router) : routeModule(router);
```

not this:

```
  const route = routeModule.config
        ? routeModule.config(router)
        : routeModule(router);
```

My `prettier.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    trailingComma: 'es5',
    tabWidth: 4,
    semi: true,
    singleQuote: true,
    printwidth: 200,
    bracketspacings: true,
};
```

Comment: I don't mind the multi-line, but I wish it would put the ? on the same line as the condition.  It reads much better that way IMO.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030709/vscode-formatting-ternary-incorrectly-within-reacts-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found a  conflict between standard and prettier.
Putting at the top of the file the following works for me

```
/* eslint-disable multiline-ternary */
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/multiline-ternary